# How to access to the raw value of a column when there is a getter?

Tags: php, model, laravel-5, getter

When there is a getter method on a model class how can I access to its original value?

e.g if there is a `public function getFooAttribute(){return 4;)}` method in the model how to get raw table column value `foo`?

Comment: two time `return`. Its TYPO or it will give error.

Comment: have you tried as `$model->foo;` what it is returning?

Comment: @AlankarMore It uses the getter method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For know I come up with `$model->getAttributes()['foo']` syntax. 
However I guess there should be a better way to achieve that.